# Java Hibernate generating number of select queries while saving the data into Database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
Hibernate: select bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_number as primary_1_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.account_code1 as account_2_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.accounting_code as accounti3_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.agency_billing_number as agency_b4_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.check_digit as check_di5_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.coupon_text as coupon_t6_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.currency_override as currency7_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.current_status as current_8_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.current_status_1 as current_9_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.destination_city as destina10_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.doc_number as doc_num11_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.eda_load_datetime as eda_loa12_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.electronic_misc_type as electro13_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.electronic_misc_type_1 as electro14_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.even_exchange_waive as even_ex15_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_category as exchang16_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_date as exchang17_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_datetime as exchang18_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_type as exchang19_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.f0_ as f20_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.fare_calculation_mode as fare_ca21_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.form_number as form_nu22_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.frequent_flyer_provider as frequen23_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.inclusive_transaction as inclusi24_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.international_sale_indicator as interna25_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.invoice_number as invoice26_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.iso_country_code as iso_cou27_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.itinerary_type as itinera28_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.last_update_datetime as last_up29_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.local_issue_datetime as local_i30_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.offer_type_code as offer_t31_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.origin_city as origin_32_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.pnr_locator_id as pnr_loc33_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.price_check_digit as price_c34_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.price_code as price_c35_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_indicator as primary36_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_description as reason_37_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_for_issue as reason_38_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_type as reason_39_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reservation_provider as reserva40_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.sequence_number as sequenc41_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.serial_number as serial_42_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.service_type as service43_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.settlement_authorization as settlem44_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.statistical_code as statist45_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.system_provider as system_46_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.tcn as tcn47_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticket_system_datetime as ticket_48_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticket_type as ticket_49_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticketing_mode as ticketi50_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticketing_provider as ticketi51_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.tour_number as tour_nu52_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.transaction_id as transac53_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.transaction_type as transac54_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.validating_number as validat55_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.validating_provider as validat56_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.waiver_code as waiver_57_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.waiver_indicator as waiver_58_50_0_ from bsp_e_ticket_good bsp_e_tick0_ where bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_number=?
Hibernate: insert into bsp_e_ticket_good (account_code1, accounting_code, agency_billing_number, check_digit, coupon_text, currency_override, current_status, current_status_1, destination_city, doc_number, eda_load_datetime, electronic_misc_type, electronic_misc_type_1, even_exchange_waive, exchange_category, exchange_transaction_date, exchange_transaction_datetime, exchange_transaction_type, f0_, fare_calculation_mode, form_number, frequent_flyer_provider, inclusive_transaction, international_sale_indicator, invoice_number, iso_country_code, itinerary_type, last_update_datetime, local_issue_datetime, offer_type_code, origin_city, pnr_locator_id, price_check_digit, price_code, primary_doc_indicator, reason_description, reason_for_issue, reason_type, reservation_provider, sequence_number, serial_number, service_type, settlement_authorization, statistical_code, system_provider, tcn, ticket_system_datetime, ticket_type, ticketing_mode, ticketing_provider, tour_number, transaction_id, transaction_type, validating_number, validating_provider, waiver_code, waiver_indicator, primary_doc_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: select bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_number as primary_1_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.account_code1 as account_2_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.accounting_code as accounti3_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.agency_billing_number as agency_b4_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.check_digit as check_di5_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.coupon_text as coupon_t6_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.currency_override as currency7_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.current_status as current_8_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.current_status_1 as current_9_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.destination_city as destina10_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.doc_number as doc_num11_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.eda_load_datetime as eda_loa12_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.electronic_misc_type as electro13_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.electronic_misc_type_1 as electro14_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.even_exchange_waive as even_ex15_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_category as exchang16_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_date as exchang17_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_datetime as exchang18_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_type as exchang19_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.f0_ as f20_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.fare_calculation_mode as fare_ca21_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.form_number as form_nu22_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.frequent_flyer_provider as frequen23_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.inclusive_transaction as inclusi24_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.international_sale_indicator as interna25_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.invoice_number as invoice26_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.iso_country_code as iso_cou27_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.itinerary_type as itinera28_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.last_update_datetime as last_up29_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.local_issue_datetime as local_i30_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.offer_type_code as offer_t31_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.origin_city as origin_32_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.pnr_locator_id as pnr_loc33_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.price_check_digit as price_c34_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.price_code as price_c35_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_indicator as primary36_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_description as reason_37_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_for_issue as reason_38_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_type as reason_39_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reservation_provider as reserva40_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.sequence_number as sequenc41_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.serial_number as serial_42_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.service_type as service43_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.settlement_authorization as settlem44_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.statistical_code as statist45_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.system_provider as system_46_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.tcn as tcn47_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticket_system_datetime as ticket_48_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticket_type as ticket_49_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticketing_mode as ticketi50_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticketing_provider as ticketi51_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.tour_number as tour_nu52_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.transaction_id as transac53_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.transaction_type as transac54_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.validating_number as validat55_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.validating_provider as validat56_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.waiver_code as waiver_57_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.waiver_indicator as waiver_58_50_0_ from bsp_e_ticket_good bsp_e_tick0_ where bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_number=?
Hibernate: insert into bsp_e_ticket_good (account_code1, accounting_code, agency_billing_number, check_digit, coupon_text, currency_override, current_status, current_status_1, destination_city, doc_number, eda_load_datetime, electronic_misc_type, electronic_misc_type_1, even_exchange_waive, exchange_category, exchange_transaction_date, exchange_transaction_datetime, exchange_transaction_type, f0_, fare_calculation_mode, form_number, frequent_flyer_provider, inclusive_transaction, international_sale_indicator, invoice_number, iso_country_code, itinerary_type, last_update_datetime, local_issue_datetime, offer_type_code, origin_city, pnr_locator_id, price_check_digit, price_code, primary_doc_indicator, reason_description, reason_for_issue, reason_type, reservation_provider, sequence_number, serial_number, service_type, settlement_authorization, statistical_code, system_provider, tcn, ticket_system_datetime, ticket_type, ticketing_mode, ticketing_provider, tour_number, transaction_id, transaction_type, validating_number, validating_provider, waiver_code, waiver_indicator, primary_doc_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: select bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_number as primary_1_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.account_code1 as account_2_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.accounting_code as accounti3_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.agency_billing_number as agency_b4_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.check_digit as check_di5_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.coupon_text as coupon_t6_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.currency_override as currency7_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.current_status as current_8_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.current_status_1 as current_9_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.destination_city as destina10_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.doc_number as doc_num11_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.eda_load_datetime as eda_loa12_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.electronic_misc_type as electro13_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.electronic_misc_type_1 as electro14_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.even_exchange_waive as even_ex15_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_category as exchang16_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_date as exchang17_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_datetime as exchang18_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.exchange_transaction_type as exchang19_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.f0_ as f20_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.fare_calculation_mode as fare_ca21_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.form_number as form_nu22_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.frequent_flyer_provider as frequen23_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.inclusive_transaction as inclusi24_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.international_sale_indicator as interna25_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.invoice_number as invoice26_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.iso_country_code as iso_cou27_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.itinerary_type as itinera28_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.last_update_datetime as last_up29_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.local_issue_datetime as local_i30_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.offer_type_code as offer_t31_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.origin_city as origin_32_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.pnr_locator_id as pnr_loc33_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.price_check_digit as price_c34_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.price_code as price_c35_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_indicator as primary36_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_description as reason_37_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_for_issue as reason_38_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reason_type as reason_39_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.reservation_provider as reserva40_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.sequence_number as sequenc41_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.serial_number as serial_42_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.service_type as service43_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.settlement_authorization as settlem44_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.statistical_code as statist45_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.system_provider as system_46_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.tcn as tcn47_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticket_system_datetime as ticket_48_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticket_type as ticket_49_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticketing_mode as ticketi50_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.ticketing_provider as ticketi51_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.tour_number as tour_nu52_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.transaction_id as transac53_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.transaction_type as transac54_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.validating_number as validat55_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.validating_provider as validat56_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.waiver_code as waiver_57_50_0_, bsp_e_tick0_.waiver_indicator as waiver_58_50_0_ from bsp_e_ticket_good bsp_e_tick0_ where bsp_e_tick0_.primary_doc_number=?
Hibernate: insert into bsp_e_ticket_good (account_code1, accounting_code, agency_billing_number, check_digit, coupon_text, currency_override, current_status, current_status_1, destination_city, doc_number, eda_load_datetime, electronic_misc_type, electronic_misc_type_1, even_exchange_waive, exchange_category, exchange_transaction_date, exchange_transaction_datetime, exchange_transaction_type, f0_, fare_calculation_mode, form_number, frequent_flyer_provider, inclusive_transaction, international_sale_indicator, invoice_number, iso_country_code, itinerary_type, last_update_datetime, local_issue_datetime, offer_type_code, origin_city, pnr_locator_id, price_check_digit, price_code, primary_doc_indicator, reason_description, reason_for_issue, reason_type, reservation_provider, sequence_number, serial_number, service_type, settlement_authorization, statistical_code, system_provider, tcn, ticket_system_datetime, ticket_type, ticketing_mode, ticketing_provider, tour_number, transaction_id, transaction_type, validating_number, validating_provider, waiver_code, waiver_indicator, primary_doc_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

...

Like This it is generating for all elements

```
private void storeInBadTables(BSP_E_Ticket ticket) {
    gson = new Gson();
    String data = gson.toJson(ticket);
    BSP_E_Ticket_Bad ticketBad = gson.fromJson(data, BSP_E_Ticket_Bad.class);
    bsp_e_ticket_bad_repo.flush();
    
    bsp_e_ticket_bad_repo.save(ticketBad);
    
}

    ticketList = bsp_e_ticket_repo.findAll();
```

Comment: `ticketBad` would be a detached entity in your case and I might be wrong but my assumption would be that `save(ticketBad)` would try a merge if that entity already existed. Of course to find out if it exists a query is needed since it's most likely not in the first level cache already.

Comment: Since primary_doc_number has a value, JPA must query the DB to determine if the entity exists and decide to use an update or an insert. If you used JPA assigned sequencing for an ID (ie leave primary_doc_number null), JPA could tell this instance is new and just insert it, avoiding the select. You will still get a select though when dealing with existing but detached objects.